# Feynman Probability lecture 6 - probability density graph

Tags: terminology, probability, error-analysis, statistics

I'm trying to understand the 6-7 graph in the [Feynman lecture 6 on
Probability chapter (6–4) A probability distribution](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html)

He says:

> "We plot $p(x)$ for three values of $N$ in Fig. 6–7. You will notice that the “half-widths” (typical spread from $x=0$) of these curves is $\sqrt N$, as we have shown it should be."

I can't see this in the graph, where are actually the "[half-widths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-width)"?

Answer (score 0):

Half-width definition: the with of the graph where it attains half the peak amplitude.

For the tall graph labeled "N=10,000" the half-width looks to be about $\Delta=280$ (i.e. from $-140$ to $+140$ of the centre).

For the medium graph labeled "N=40,000" which has $4$ times the number of samples, the half-width looks to be about 560, or $2 \Delta$, which is $\sqrt{4}\Delta$.

For the short graph labeled "N=160,000" which has $16\times$ the number of samples, the half-width looks to be about 1120, or $4 \Delta$, which is $\sqrt{16}\Delta$.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't get it how does the half width equals  √N in this case? maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the page number 6-6 in the chapter where deviation of the NH from its expected value  (N/2) is explained. Here he put the value of 'N' as 30 and finds the typical value of k as 2.8 units from 15(expected value). From the Fig 6-2 it is seen that width of the curve (most of the outcomes falls)  is measured 3 units from the center. 
Similarly here he might take Sqrroot of N to find the half width. (I think it is Sqrrootof N divided by 2 as in the previous case). By the term Half width I think it is some what similar to the 3dB gain in the efficiency curve.